# Change of coordinates in $R^{n}$ where the diagonal goes to $x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

Say I have a system of coordinates $\{y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}\}$.

I'd like to get a new system of coordinates $\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\}$ where the diagonal $y_{1}=y_{2}=...=y_{n}$ is $x_{1}$, and I'd like to have the other lines related to $y_{i+i}-y_{i}=0$, or have $y_{i}-y_{i-1}$ be a new variable, something like that. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can say that $x_j=y_j-y_{j-1}$, $2\le j\le n$.

Then the directing vector of the line $y_1=\ldots y_n$ is, of course, $(1,\ldots,1)$, and it will be mapped to the line spanned by $(1,0,\ldots,0)$. In other words, you can take $x_1=\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}{y_j}$.

It is easy to check that this change of variables is invertible.

Comment: That's right, thanks!